# How to count correct answer quize in Naravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$correcrt_answer = array(1=>A; 2=>B); the correct answer from database
$user_answer = array(1=>B; 2=>B); the answer from user
```

How can I count the the correct answer/total and how to display each
`$correcrt_answer[$value] == $user_answer[$value]` if they are the same is correct?

Comment: Welcome to OS, please look at [How to Ask](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array_intersect_assoc($correcrt_answer, $user_answer);

$total = count($correcrt_answer);

$correct = count($result);
```